# File explorer in DDMS is empty

Tags: android, ddms

When I open DDMS -> File explorer, it is empty, how to resolve it?

Here is my DDMS window.

[image: ddms]

File Explorer window.

[image: File Explorer]

Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Comment: Can you post your code? Please, take two minutes to read these links and improve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask